# What is the difference between CurrentDomain and UserDomainName?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, dns, active-directory

Recently, a customer complained that our product was not populating the domain name.

Our code uses the Username and the User's Domain Name to query their membership rolls in Active Directory.

In our code, we use [Environment.UserDomainName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userdomainname.aspx):

```
var domain = Environment.UserDomainName;
```

When I looked at this simple line of code, I discovered it could raise the **PlatformNotSupportedException** and the **InvalidOperationException**.

[image: Environment.UserDomainName]

Looking for an alternative method of reading the domain name, I came across [AppDomain.CurrentDomain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.currentdomain.aspx):

```
var domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.Split(".".ToArray())[0];
```

That is nice, but it also appears to have an **AppDomainUnloadedException** that could be triggered.

[image: AppDomain.CurrentDomain]

**First Question:**
Will these 2 methods always return the same information for a given user who is running our program on a local PC?

**Second Question:**
Is one method less "exception prone" than the other (again, for a given user who is running our program on a local PC)?

**Last Question:**
Is there a method of getting the local domain name of the user running our application that will not cause an exception to be thrown?

**EDIT:** For Tyler Lee

[image: For Tyler Lee]

Comment: Which exception did you get when trying to use `Environment.UserDomainName`?

Comment: Our customer reports a PlatformNotSupportedException. I do not get any errors on my development PC. That's why I am asking the question.

Comment: What platform is your customer running on?

Comment: @TylerLee - I sent that question to their rep to ask them last week, but I have not heard back. I know they are testing on a PC, but I don't know if it's standalone or part of a domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [AppDomain.CurrentDomain Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.currentdomain.aspx) is the domain of the current application and the current thread.

In other words, this is the domain of a project.

In Visual Studio, under a Project's Properties page, this would be referred to as the Project's Assembly Name.

[image: Visual Studio Assembly name]

By contrast, [Environment.UserDomainName Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userdomainname.aspx) is the name of the network that the current user is logged in through.

The two are not related.

Answer (score 2):

Did you even try to see what the value of `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName` was?

[image]

To Answer question 1: No, they will not.
Question 2 does not seem to apply considering question 1
Question 3: probably not. `Environment.UserDomainName` seems to be the source for getting a network domain name, and as you found, it has the potential to generate exceptions. The MSDN page gives details on when those exceptions are thrown, and you should write your code to be able to deal with it if they happen.

Comment: Not on my machine. They are both the same. That's why I came here to ask.

Comment: @jp2code I see your additional picture. Like my example, the two values do not match. I'm confused if you saw this why you asked if they would match. They are similar in that your application is named the same as your network domain, but `HARRIS` is not equal to `Harris.vshost.exe` (or even Harris.exe` when not running under visual studio debug)

Comment: Microsoft's documentation was confusing. I did not realize that one was specifically for project application information and the other was for network domain information. StackOverflow.com will not let me delete the question, though, because it has an answer.

Comment: It was just by some crazy coincidence that the project's selected assembly name happened to be the same as the network's domain name.